# Update values in JavaScript Functions - VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I have a VF page which has a commandLink button which used for adding values to a table.

I want to display success or error messages on different lang base on a custom Setting object.

I'm using "SweetAlert" for customizing alert popups.

**VF PAGE:**

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!addToTable}" value="{!$Label.pf_Add_Item}" reRender="table-s,quantity,pricing,addtotableId" oncomplete="doneAdding();" />
```

**JS FUNCTION IN VF:**

```
 function doneAdding(){
   swal("{!AddingItems[0]}", "{!AddingItems[1]}", "success");
}
```

**APEX METHOD:**

```
public List<String> getAddingItems(){
        UI_Messages__c uiM = UI_Messages__c.getValues('Add Items');
        List<String> customSettingList = new List<String>();
        if(this.lang=='es'){

            customSettingList.add(uim.Message_To_Display_Top__c);
            customSettingList.add(uim.Message_To_Display_Bottom__c);
        }else{
            customSettingList.add(uim.Message_To_Display_Top_Eng__c);
            customSettingList.add(uim.Message_To_Display_Bottom_Eng__c);
        }

        return customSettingList;
    }
```

I didn't really understand why, but the first run of the constructor is called to this apex method and put in the "customsettinglist" List the values base on the default lang- which is "es".

Later, when I change the lang, It's still the same values in the JS function, but when I printed the values in my apex class, it did change.

So actually my issue is that my javascript function doesn't have the new values when the `Incomplete` is called, It's not updated.

I tried also to call the function `getAddingItems();` from the method : `addToTable()` but It still not change the JS array values.

How can I make it updated as well?

**EDIT:**

The bottom line question, is how to render a JS function to get the latest value?

In my JS function, I call to Apex method - and it gets a default value at the beginning From my apex method.

But when I call the "doneAdding" function again, It still has the previous value although it changed in my apex class.

I hope that the code I supplied will be ok with this explanation.

Thanks again.

Comment: code in question is incomplete - unable to understand the full flow

Comment: Hi @salesforce-sas I added an "Edit" section in my post, I hope it more clear now. Thanks for your help!